# Fixed header scroll to tag issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having issues making the links in my header scroll to the tag. Because it is a fixed header it scrolls past the area and the content is behind the header. How can I fix it to where it goes to the bottom of the header? I am also using `box-sizing: border-box;` if that has anything to do with it. Thanks for the help.

here is the jquery:

```
$(".scrolltotag").click(function(event){        
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 600);
});
```

all the links in the nav have a class of `scrolltotag` and an `href="#tag"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding `- $('header').outerHeight()` after `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top` thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

// Get the height of the header

var headerHeight = $(".header").height();

// Attach the click event

$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault();

var target = $(this).attr("href"); 
var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - headerHeight;

$('html').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600, function(){
window.location.hash = "" + target;

$('html').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 0); });
});